# R: Read csv with row and column name

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv with column name in first row of the file, and column name in first column of the file, like this:

```
ColName1 ColName2 ... ColNameN
RowName1 ..
RowName2 ..
RowNameN ..
```

If I use this command:
read.csv("/Users/MNeptune/Documents/workspace R/simulatedProfiles.csv", header=TRUE)

I read correctly only columns name but not row name. What i can do to read row name?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try `read.csv("filename.csv", row.names = 1, header= TRUE)`.

Comment: row.names is available only in read.table as per this [doc](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html)

Comment: But its working in read.csv also so read.csv is add on to read.table.

Answer (score 7):

There is a `row.names` option to read.csv (inherited from read.table) in which you can specify the column in the file to be used as row.names.

```
read.csv("/path/to/file", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may need to convert a `csv` file as a matrix. This can be obtained by using `as.matrix` command. But if you need to have the header as column names and the first-row names as row names, then prepare your file with one blank space at the start of the first row. As an example,

```
    ,x,y
Anbu,12,89
Arivu,15,32
Siva,23,17
```

Then first issue command

```
data<-read.csv("file.csv", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
```

Then issue command

```
datam<-as.matrix(data)
```

you will get a matrix object with row and column names as found in the csv file.